# How could I find a slant asymptote of a function like x*e^(1/x)

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Is there a general way of finding this. Usually what I find on the internet is dividing the function by ax + b but I can't seem to make it work

Comment: For $x\to\infty$ we have$$xe^{1/x}=x\left(1+\frac1x+o\left(\frac1x\right)\right)=x+1+o(1)$$

Comment: I don't undersand. Where did the o(1/x) come from?

Comment: An application of Taylor's theorem on the function $e^{1/x}$. I could have also written $O(1/x^2)$ instead.

Comment: Fair enough. Is there a simpler way though?

Comment: See the answer below. Although in order to calculate these limits one is going to have to use the above result in some way to study the functions behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Use differential geometry!

The oblique asymptotes have the equation:

$$y=kx+b, \space \text{ with } \space \space k = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}, \space \space b = \lim_{x \to \infty} [f(x) - kx].$$

Comment: This is right. Although it didn't help me a lot because the finding b is so hard for me in this case. But now I know how to do it